# Wait for many asynchronous calls to perform callback

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, block

I want to synchronize some data with a web service. For each item I have to make a asynchronous call.

I want to have a completion block witch is called, when each item was synchronized. For each item I am able to perform a completion block. Now, I don't know a good way how to do it.

This is the interface:

```
-(void) synchronizeItemsOnComplete:(CompleteBlock) block {
    NSArray* items = // get items
    for (int i = 0, n = [items count]; i < n; i++) {
       [self synchronizeItem:[items objectAtIndex:i] onComplete:^{
          // What do do here?
       }];
    }
    // And/or here?
}

-(void) synchronizeItemOnComplete:(CompleteBlock) block {
    // do something
    block();
}
```

How can I wait for the synchronization and then perform the block?

I tried something like this:

```
NSArray* items = // get items

__block int countOfItemsUntilDone = [items count];

for (int i = 0, n = countOfItemsUntilDone; i < n; i++) {
    [self synchronizeItem:[items objectAtIndex:i] onComplete:^{
        countOfItemsUntilDone--;
    }];
}

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("wait for syncing", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    while (countOfItemsUntilDone > 0) {
        usleep(1000); // wait a little bit
    }
    block();
});
dispatch_release(queue);
```

But I think this is a quite bad way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of spinning in a loop waiting for the counter to equal zero, check the counter value each time you decrement it, then fire an event when it reaches zero.

```
 -(void) synchronizeItemsOnComplete:(CompleteBlock) block {
    NSArray* items = // get items
    __block NSUInteger remaining = [items count];

    for (ItemClass* item in items) {
       [self synchronizeItemImage:item onComplete:^{
            --remaining;
            if (remaining == 0) {
                block();
            }
       }];
    }
 }
```

To explain why it feels wrong, there are two things you're doing here that you should do either never or rarely:

- Using background queues. This is difficult and bug-prone. Don't do it without reading up a *lot* about writing concurrent code. You also only really need to do this if an operation blocks for a substantial amount of time (eg., to read a file from disk, or perform an intensive calculation). Don't assume you need to do it unless you have a good reason (eg., a measurable performance problem).
- Spinning in a loop, checking a variable for changes and calling sleep. You should *never* do this.

Also, if you're looping over the elements in an array, the `for ... in` syntax is much nicer (and potentially more efficient) calling objectAtIndex: on each index.

Answer (score 2):

Never check or decrement shared memory in different threads like this, it can cause races.  Use a dispatch group to do what you're doing.

```
dispatch_queue_t myBGQueue;
dispatch_group_t itemsGroup = dispatch_group_create();

for (ItemClass *item in items) {
    dispatch_group_async(itemsGroup, myBGQueue, ^{
        [self synchronizeItemImage:item];
    });
}

/* execution will sleep here until all the blocks added in the `for` complete */
dispatch_group_wait(itemsGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

dispatch_release(itemsGroup);
```

Comment: Oh... I didn't make that point clear. That called synchronizeItemImage method starts a asynchronous request via RESTKit. So, to perform that method async or with `waitUntilDone:` probably wouldn't work. To avoid decrementing shared memory in different threads I could execute the block from Chris Devereux's solution on a serial dispatch queue, or is this bad, too?

Comment: Oh. In that case, as long as the completion handlers are called on the main thread you can just decrement some variable.  Or better, decrement a property on your windowController or application delegate and use KVO notifications to find out when it hits zero.

Answer (score 1):

You can use these to use synchronously.

[GCD](http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.in/2009/09/guide-to-blocks-grand-central-dispatch.html) and [this](http://www.fieryrobot.com/blog/2010/09/01/synchronization-using-grand-central-dispatch/)

`performSelector:waitUntilDone:YES`